# Nginx Ubuntu PHP5 - not found php-fastcgi.pid

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

I was setting-up Nginx with PHP5 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 TLS Server, and follow this instructions -

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/php-fastcgi/ubuntu-10.04-lucid

Everything is fine before I run /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi start, the php-fastcgi is a script -

```
#!/bin/bash

PHP_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/php-fastcgi
FASTCGI_USER=www-data
FASTCGI_GROUP=www-data
PID_DIR=/var/run/php-fastcgi
PID_FILE=/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.pid
RET_VAL=0

case "$1" in
    start)
      if [[ ! -d $PID_DIR ]]
      then
        mkdir $PID_DIR
        chown $FASTCGI_USER:$FASTCGI_GROUP $PID_DIR
        chmod 0770 $PID_DIR
      fi
      if [[ -r $PID_FILE ]]
      then
        echo "php-fastcgi already running with PID `cat $PID_FILE`"
        RET_VAL=1
      else
        $PHP_SCRIPT
        RET_VAL=$?
      fi
  ;;
    stop)
      if [[ -r $PID_FILE ]]
      then
        kill `cat $PID_FILE`
        rm $PID_FILE
        RET_VAL=$?
      else
        echo "Could not find PID file $PID_FILE"
        RET_VAL=1
      fi
  ;;
    restart)
      if [[ -r $PID_FILE ]]
      then
        kill `cat $PID_FILE`
        rm $PID_FILE
        RET_VAL=$?
      else
        echo "Could not find PID file $PID_FILE"
      fi
      $PHP_SCRIPT
      RET_VAL=$?
  ;;
    status)
      if [[ -r $PID_FILE ]]
      then
        echo "php-fastcgi running with PID `cat $PID_FILE`"
        RET_VAL=$?
      else
        echo "Could not find PID file $PID_FILE, php-fastcgi does not appear to be running"
      fi
  ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: php-fastcgi {start|stop|restart|status}"
      RET_VAL=1
  ;;
esac
exit $RET_VAL
```

and it give me this message -

```
spawn-fcgi: opening PID-file '/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.pid' failed: No such file or directory
```

Apparently there is no php-fastcgi.pid in the folder, even strange, there is no php-fastcgi folder in /var/run, I installed php by this command -

```
apt-get install php5-cli php5-cgi spawn-fcgi psmisc
```

So is there anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't exist, did you mean I should create one?

Comment: Can u answer the question, and then I can choose your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the missing directory and make it writable by the web server user:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/php-fastcgi/
sudo chgrp www-data /var/run/php-fastcgi/
sudo chmod 0770 /var/run/php-fastcgi/
```